# Using dojo/touch with event delegation

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is it possible to delegate dojo/touch events using dojo/query and selectors?

Given I've included `dojo/query` and `dojo/touch` as `touch`, the following pseudocode represents what I want.

```
on(target, '.myClass:touch.press', 'myPressHandler');
```

This obviously does not work because touch.press is a function, not an event.

Another way, which I'm trying to avoid would be:

```
on(target, '.myClass:mousedown', 'myPressHandler');
on(target, '.myClass:touchstart', 'myPressHandler');
```

Yeah, it only saves a line, but hey still saves typing a line, and over a bunch of files or targets or types of events lines add up!

EDIT
This question would also apply to Dojox/gesture/tap, since it behaves similarly. Given `dojox/gesture/tap` as `tap`,

```
on(target, '.myClass:tap', 'myPressHandler');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojox gesture tap. Should do what you need. 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/gesture.html

```
define(["dojo/on", "dojox/gesture/tap"], function(on, tap){
  on(target, on.selector(".myClass", tap), ''myPressHandler);
}
```

or for dojo/touch

```
define(["dojo/on", "dojox/touch"], function(on, touch){
  on(target, on.selector(".myClass", touch.press), ''myPressHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I don't see the ability to delegate events in Dojox gesture...I'm not looking for another module to use, I'm looking for the ability to delegate dojo.press or dojox.gesture.tap.

Comment: not sure what you are looking for tap equates to what you seem to ask for, see edit above.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I'm asking about event delegation using selectors. See 'Event Delegation' on [Events with Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/events/). See edit to my original question to see how Dojox gesture tap doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: you can use the on.selector to map the top::http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/on#selector